# Azure Mobile App Home controller

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, azure-mobile-services

Using a **Azure Mobile Server** project (not services), how do I replace the default blue home page of the app? (the one with "*This mobile service is up and running*")

I'm talking this kind of app: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/17/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/

I tried this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Home/, but there's is no documentation at all.

I'm trying to get a project that can run **Web API**, **Azure Mobile Server** and **default Controllers** all together.

Comment: Does your default page say "this mobile service is up and running" (it's a black page to me usually) or "This web app has been successfully created" (blue page)? Just trying to help with the right problem first. If you did the quickstart on the page you linked I expect the second page.

Comment: Blue page with "This mobile app is up and running". I'm running it locally with a local SQL Server.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. The whole suite of technologies, whether it's mobile service, mobile app service, or API service and etc, they are all based on web api. It just simply provide a backend web service for different use cases. The blue page you get is your API documentation, you can't replace this. You can write your own web front end that consumes the backend web service.

Comment: Web API and regular MVC controllers are not independent, they can coexist in the same service. Azure mobile server should provide a way to remove or at least change the default routing of the documentation pages so that the home controller can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blogpost](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/17/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/) might be a hint.

It details how to config the Mobile App and mentions a extension method `AddMobileAppHomeController()` that appears to be part of the `UseDefaultConfiguration()` method.

I guess you can eliminate this from you configuration and a